# Proof of Chain Rule using Nonstandard Analysis

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

I am trying to make an introduction and make myself comfortable with the Nonstandard Analysis in order to gain intuition for derivatives and integration. I am trying to prove myself the famous Chain Rule for differentiation by using the principles of Nonstandard Analysis but I am stuck at somewhere and I am trying to understand where I am doing wrong.

Here is the procedure I am following.

We have two functions $x=f(t)$ and $y=g(x)$ hence $y=g(f(t))$ $f$ has derivative at $t$ and $g$ has derivative at $f(t)$.

As it is widely known, chain rule states that the derivate of $y$ with regards to $t$ is:

$\frac{dy}{dt} = g'(f(t))f'(t) = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$

Now, I first write the slope equation of the $x=f(t)$ with regards to $t$:

$\frac{\Delta{x}}{\Delta{t}} = f'(t) + \epsilon$

Whre $\epsilon$ is an infitesimal. Now according to Increment Theorem, it is

$f(t + dt) - f(t) = \Delta{x} = f'(t)dt + \epsilon dt$

Where $dt = \Delta{t}$. So we can write the differential of x as $dx = f'(t)dt$.

Now I move to the $y=g(x)$ and apply the same methodology. The independent variable $t$ has increased by $dt$ which causes an infitesimal change $\Delta{x}$ in the dependent variable $x$, so the slope equation for $g(x) = g(f(t))$ at $x = f(t)$ is:

$\frac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta{x}} = g'(f(t)) + \delta$

Where $\delta$ is infinitesimal.

Applying Increment Theorem:

$g(f(t + dt)) - g(f(t)) = g(x + \Delta{x}) - g(x) = \Delta{y} = g'(f(t))\Delta{x} + \delta \Delta{x}$

Now I divide all sides of the above equation by $dt$ which is equal to $\Delta{t}$:

$\frac{\Delta{y}}{dt} = g'(f(t))\frac{\Delta{x}}{dt} + \delta \frac{\Delta{x}}{dt}$.

Taking the standard part of the above expression should yield the derivative we are looking for:

$st(\frac{\Delta{y}}{dt}) = st(g'(f(t))\frac{\Delta{x}}{dt}) + st(\delta \frac{\Delta{x}}{dt}) = g'(f(t))st(\frac{\Delta{x}}{dt}) + 0 = g'(f(t))f'(t)$

The line above actually completes the proof, but what I want is to express the equation in the form of $\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$ as well, since it is not a mere notation anymore in Nonstandard Analysis and all $dy, dx, dt$ have actual values attached to them. This where I run into a problem.

We know that it is $\frac{dx}{dt} = f'(t)$ already. But from the Increment theorem of $\Delta{y}$ it is $\Delta{y} = g'(f(t))\Delta{x} + \delta \Delta{x}$, so, the differential $dy$ is:

$dy = g'(f(t))\Delta{x}$ and $\frac{dy}{\Delta{x}}=g'(f(t))$.

Now I substitute both $g'(f(t))$ and $f'(t)$ with differential representations and it becomes:

$g'(f(t))f'(t) = \frac{dy}{\Delta{x}} \frac{dx}{dt}$

As you can see $\Delta{x}$ and $dx$ are different values and do not cancel each other out. So I cannot write the chain rule in the form of differentials. I think I am making a mistake in the procedure I am following but I cannot figure it out, so I turned here for help. What is incorrect here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of introducing $dx$ as $f'(x)dx$, I would work with $\Delta t$ and $\Delta x$ throughout.  This way one gets the relation $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t} = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$.  Note that there is a technical point here that needs to be handled when $\Delta x$ vanishes (in which case one can't divide by it).  This is a relation among hyperreal quantities rather than real quantities, and is therefore not the chain rule yet.  It is only at this stage that I would apply the standard part function to the relation $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t} = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$, so as to get the relation between the derivatives.

Comment: If we apply the standard part function to $\frac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta{t}}=\frac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta{x}}\frac{\Delta{x}}{\Delta{t}}$, it becomes $st(\frac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta{t}})=st(\frac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta{x}})st(\frac{\Delta{x}}{\Delta{t}})$. At this stage $st(\frac{\Delta{x}}{\Delta{t}})$ is equal to $\frac{dx}{dt}$ (Assuming $\Delta{t}=dt$).And $st(\frac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta{x}})$ is again equal to $\frac{dy}{\Delta{x}}$ since it is $dy = g'(f(t))\Delta{x}$. So we again end up with $g'(f(t))f'(t) = \frac{dy}{\Delta{x}} \frac{dx}{dt}$.

Comment: (Continuing from the previous comment) The problem is when taking the standard part of a difference ratio like $\frac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta{x}}$ for derivative calculation, the denominator $\Delta{x}$ does not change but the nominator $\Delta{y}$ becomes $dy$. I may be making a mistake in these calculations, but I still cannot see where...

Comment: When $x$ is treated as the *independent* variable in calculating the derivative of $y=g(x)$, by definition $dx$ is equal to $\Delta x$. You are getting needlessly involved with the differential notation.  *By definition* $g'(x)$ is the standard part of $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$.

Comment: If you prefer to use the differential notation throughout, what you could say is that once $dx$ is chosen in such a way that $dx=f'(x)dt$, we choose the infinitesimal increment $\Delta x$ of the independent variable $x$ to be equal to $dx$ when we deal with $y=g(x)$. If you are bothered by the clash of notation with the previous $\Delta x$ (when $x$ was the dependent variable of the relation $x=f(t)$), you can just denote the previous one by $\Delta' x$ instead, since in any case it is not present in the final answer $dy/dt = dy/dx\;dx/dt$.

Comment: What I was doing was making both $y$ and $x$ depend on $t$. So, when we independently change $t$ by $\Delta{t}$ it caused a change of $\Delta{x}$ in $x=f(t)$ and the change $\Delta{x}$ caused a change of $\Delta{y}$ in $g(y)$ in turn, so in a sense $x$ and $y$ were *not independent, both of them*. From what I get from your last comment, I should first calculate $st(\frac{\Delta{x}}{\Delta{t}}) = \frac{dx}{dt}$ where $t$ is independent and $\Delta{t} = dt$ as normal, but then I should use $dx=f'(t)dt$ for incrementing $y=g(x)$ and not $\Delta{x}=f'(t)dt + \epsilon dt$.

Comment: (Continuing from the previous comment) Then it really works since $st(\frac{\Delta{y}}{dx}) = \frac{dy}{dx}$ and it leads to $dy/dt = dy/dx dx/dt$. But doesn't that violate the "chaining" behavior then? I mean, a change of $\Delta{t}=dt$ for the input of $x=f(t)$ results in a change of $\Delta{x}$ and the input to $y=g(x)$ changes to $g(x + \Delta{x})$ as the result, it does not change to $y=g(x + dx)$. Why does the differential approach not work for the $g(x + \Delta{x})$ case? I hope I clarified my thoughts sufficiently.

Comment: The differential approach does work and is compatible with the chaining behavior, since it produces the relation $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t}= \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$. The advantage of working with infinitesimals here is that one has the tool of the standard part.  Namely, applying the standard part to this relation to obtain the chain rule can only be implemented when there are infinitesimals around.  It cannot be implemented in the context of the real continuum alone...

Comment: ... Your problem seems to be that you want to eat the cake and have it, too: namely to preserve the chaining behavior and also have the ratio of infinitesimals equal the derivative on the nose.

Comment: (1)I think I expressed myself wrong, in all my questions I always thought in terms of infinitesimals. When I wrote $dx = f'(t)dt$ or $dy = g'(x)dx$ all three of $dy, dx$ and $dt$ were infinitesimal quantities, they were not finite real numbers. I am already studying Nonstandard Analysis since the classic Calculus with limits was never intuitive for me.

Comment: (2) I follow H. Jerome Keisler's online book on the Calculus with Nostandard Analysis at http://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html. In his explanation of the chain rule in the Chapter 2, he proved the rule by using a similar approach I have taken in my main question body and reached the result that $st(\frac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta{t}}) = g'(f(t))f'(t).$ This is completely OK for me. But then, he suddenly starts to use the notation $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$ . In this notation, all three "d" terms are infinitesimal quantities, as well.

Comment: (3) What I tried was to reach the $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$ infinitesimal form of the chain rule from the infinitesimal form of $\frac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta{t}} = \frac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta{x}}\frac{\Delta{x}}{\Delta{t}}$ .

Comment: (4) When I take the standard part as $st(\frac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta{t}}) = st(\frac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta{x}})st(\frac{\Delta{x}}{\Delta{t}})$, $st(\frac{\Delta{x}}{\Delta{t}})$ outputs $\frac{dx}{dt}$ where $dt=\Delta{t}$. $st(\frac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta{x}})$ outputs $\frac{dy}{dx}$ where $dx=\Delta{x}$. This is the problematic part,since the $dx$ from $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and from $\frac{dx}{dt}$ are actually two different quantities and do not cancel each other. So, I cannot write the chain rule in "infinitesimal differential" notation of $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$.

Comment: I agree with your comments.  In the formula $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$ the two symbol $dx$ do not have the same meaning, so you cannot literally cancel them. Nonetheless, what I was trying to point out that it is still possible literally to cancel out the infinitesimal in the numerator and denominator in the formula $\frac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta{t}} = \frac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta{x}}\frac{\Delta{x}}{\Delta{t}}$, which shows the advantage of the infinitesimal method.  Namely, the advantage is that this formula can be immediately related to chain rule $g(f(x))'=g'(f(x))f'(x)$...

Comment: ... by taking the standard part, which is something one cannot do in the context of the real continuum alone (I did not mean to imply that you wish to assign real values to $dx$'s). Similarly, Keisler passes to the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ notation because it is an equivalent form of the $f'(x)$ notation, not because he assumes one can literally cancel out the $dx$'s (in which case there would be nothing to prove).

Comment: Just to summarize, of one is willing to give up the "chaining behavior" you mentioned earlier, one can set $dx=f'(t)dt$ and then use $dx$ as the input of $g(x)$ so as to find the appropriate $dy$ such that $dy=g'(x)dx$.  Then one will indeed have the literal equality of fractions $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much easier way to do this. You don't even need the increment theorem for it.

First, let's limit our focus to functions defined at the point $(0, 0)$. If we can prove the chain rule for $f_0$ and $g_0$ at $(0, 0)$, then we can prove it for any two functions $f$ and $g$ at any point $(t, y)$ by setting
$f_{0}=a\mapsto f\left(t+a\right)-f\left(t\right)$
and
$g_{0}=a\mapsto g\left(f\left(t\right)+a\right)-g\left(f\left(t\right)\right)$.

Second, let's think of functions as constrained sets of points. The antecedent of the chain rule postulates that there are two real numbers $\dot x, \dot y$, and a set of infinitessimal triples:

$\left(\Delta t, \Delta x, \Delta y\right)$

Constrained by:

- $\Delta t \neq 0$
- $\exists \epsilon_x\ \left(\Delta x = \left( \dot x+\epsilon_x \right)\Delta t\right)$
- $\exists \epsilon_y\ \left(\Delta y = \left( \dot y+\epsilon_y \right)\Delta x\right)$

(In other words: $\Delta y$ is approximately proportional to $\Delta x$, which in turn is approximately proportional to $\Delta t$. $\dot y$ and $\dot x$ are the respective proportionality constants.)

And the consequent claims that $\Delta t$ and $\Delta y$ are constrained by:

$\exists \epsilon_{xy}\ \left(\Delta y = \left( \dot x \dot y + \epsilon_{xy} \right)\Delta t\right)$

Assuming the antecedent, the consequent can be proven using substitution:

$\Delta y = \left(\dot y + \epsilon_y\right)\Delta x
= \left(\dot y + \epsilon_y\right)\left(\dot x + \epsilon_x\right)\Delta t
=
\left( \dot x\dot y + \epsilon_x\dot y + \epsilon_y\dot x + \epsilon_x \epsilon_y \right) \Delta t$

The existence of $\epsilon_{xy}$ is thus proven by constructing it as
$\epsilon_x\dot y + \epsilon_y\dot x + \epsilon_x \epsilon_y$.

---

Differentials don't really have a place in this. You don't need them. I think I see what you want them for: you want real numbers that characterize the relationships between $t$ and $x$; $x$ and $y$; $t$ and $y$. And you want to call these numbers $\frac{dx}{dt}$, $\frac{dy}{dx}$, $\frac{dy}{dt}$.

The thing is, there are already numbers for this purpose: $\dot x$, $\dot y$, $\dot x \dot y$. (aka $f^\prime(t)$, $g^\prime(f(t))$, $g^\prime(f(t))f^\prime(t)$.)

Furthermore, if $dt$, $dx$, $dy$ are just values, then
$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$
is just a tautology. In order to express anything at all using that equation, you have to equivocate between $dy = \dot x \dot y dt$ and $dy = \dot y dx$, *and* you have to equivocate between $dx = \Delta x$ and $dx = \dot x dt$.

Differentials work when you only want to refer to one variable's dependence on one other variable.